# Ширина блока зависит от ширины контейнера?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть блок с текстом, у которого есть блок-врапер.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bada55;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="block">
    test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно получить блок, ширина которого будет зависеть от контента, но из-за ширины врапера у него ширина самого длинного слова

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите `position: relative;`

Comment: Я этот блок использую для тултипа, мне необходим position: relative

Comment: Не понятно, что имеется в виду... может в .block добавить просто `width: 200px;` вместо максимальной ширины?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ширина блока должна зависеть от контента, она должна быть динамической

Comment: @dev_jun при данной структуре и с явным ограничением ширины родителя сделать динамическую ширину у потомка без костылей не получится. Приведите более ёмкий кусок кода, где будет виден контент и его взаимодействие с тултипом.

Comment: Описал в отдельном вопросе

Comment: @Arsenty, ну от браузера зависит. В современных получится, в более старых немного покостыльнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если браузер [поддерживает](//caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width) `width: max-content`, то оно отлично подойдёт:

```js
~function () {
  var s = "test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w"
  var i = s.length
  var div = document.querySelector(".block");

  setInterval(function () {
    div.textContent = s.slice(0, i = ++i % (s.length + 1))
  }, 100)
}()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bada55;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 25px;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оберни его в дополнительный блок достаточной ширины, а для того, чтобы он не мешал взаимодействовать с другими элементами поставь ему `pointer-events: none`.

```js
~function () {
  var s = "test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w"
  var i = s.length
  var div = document.querySelector(".block");

  setInterval(function () {
    div.textContent = s.slice(0, i = ++i % (s.length + 1))
  }, 100)
}()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.space {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: all;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bada55;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 25px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="space">
    <div class="block">
      test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

И ещё костыль через `right` с `transform`ом:

```js
~function () {
  var s = "test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w"
  var i = s.length
  var div = document.querySelector(".block");

  setInterval(function () {
    div.textContent = s.slice(0, i = ++i % (s.length + 1))
  }, 100)
}()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  right: -220px;
  transform: translateX(-220px) translateX(100%);
  padding: 10px;
  background: #bada55;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 25px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w test 123 123w w31 w
  </div>
</div>
```